# WavesSvc64.exe causing Dell XPS 9570 with Windows 10 Insider to freeze after startup

Tags: windows-10, dell-xps

I usually never restart or shut down my computer, since I always put it in hybernation mode, so I don't know when this issue started.

## System

- Windows 10 Insider (19592.1001)
- Dell XPS 9570 i7, 32GB

## Symptoms after reboot

#### The first 5 minutes or so

- Windows starts normally
- Fans spin up
- Mouse, keyboard works
- Interacting with Windows works normal
- Task manager does not show any process eating up CPU or RAM
- Procmon64 shows the usuall event log (autoscrolling)

#### The next 10 minutes

- Windows becomes unresponsive, all programs freeze
- Mouse, keyboard become laggy (~ 1fps)
- Interacting with Windows impossible
- Task manager still not showing any process eating up CPU or RAM
- Procmon64 lags with autoscroll showing a bunch of WavesSvc64.exe events, and eventually stops autoscrolling at all, because of total freeze

#### Finally

- Everything works normal again
- Procmon64 starts autoscrolling again

## Things tried so far

- Disable all Startup apps (didn't work)
- Uninstall Waves MaxxAudio Pro

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this problem happen if you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: Open Windows normally and do nothing with it for 1 minute. Open a command prompt (CMD.EXE). Type __CHKDSK /F__  then close the Command prompt, wait 5 seconds, then reboot. If that does not help, turn off hibernation (comand prompt __powercfg /hibernate off__) restart then turn /hibernate on. This gives it a fresh start with the Hibernation file. If all else fails, run a memory check. Sometimes clearing the Pagefile helps also. I have had problems where Pagefile.sys was causing errors with opening applications. Turned it off then, reboot, then back on.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up uninstalling and removing the Waves-driver for Realtek.

1. DeviceManager -> Sound -> Realtek Audio -> Uninstall
2. `dism /online /get-drivers /format:table` locate the inf-file of the corrupt driver
3. `pnputil.exe /d oemXX.inf` (where XX is the number of the file)
4. Reboot
5. Install Realtek Audio drivers from Dell support website again
6. Reboot
7. Enabled Waves MaxxAudio Service Application under Startup Apps

Comment: This stupid application has been the bane of my existence. Wish there was some way to fully uninstall it and use a generic driver, but haven't had any luck. This did the trick for now. Kudos!

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do you also have extreme GPU and throttling issue lately with the newest BIOS 1.17.1? My 9570 would throttle down to 0.7GHz when doing GPU intensive tasks, like gaming or working in UE4.

Comment: I'm on an XPS 7590 BIOS v1.8.1, but I haven't noticed anything. I also don't do a lot of GPU-intensive stuff... Hope you figure something out!

Comment: Sadly this is not working in 2022. Windows will just install the old driver by itself, including WavesSvc64.exe. One reboot and it's all over again. It takes 100% of one CPU core in my system. It does nothing. It doesn't respond to user inputs. It's a malware.

Comment: @Yvon I'm sorry, but I can't help you anymore. I use a Legion 5 and Linux as my daily driver now.